# How to check the number of float shares of a stock?

Tags: stocks, shares

https://ir.aterian.io/static-files/dfc62a8a-ba54-4202-aaa6-864d47fb6f51

The 10-Q of ATER only lists the number of outstanding shares.

Morningstar lists the number of float shares of ATER as 32.32 Mil.

https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/ater/quote

WSJ lists the number of float shares as 14.04 M.

https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/ATER

The two numbers are drastically different. How to check which one is correct?